# Checkboxes and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox, scripting

Not the usual case of just knowing how to "insert" checkboxes into the database , I have a form with several checkboxes ...about 25 checkboxes each with the same name and values from 1-25 , Now the thing is I need them to have the same name in order to run a script which prevents the selection of no more than 4 checkboxes ...

HTML Code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb" id="EngineeringWorkshops" value=1 onclick='chkcontrol(0)';>
<label for="EngineeringWorkshop"> Engineering Workshops           </label>
```

PHP Code

```
$engineeringworkshops = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['cob']); 


    $sql="INSERT INTO courses (studentid, engworkshops)
    VALUES ('$studentid', '$engineeringwokshops')";
```

engworkshops column type is tinyint(4) default value set to 0

Comment: and the question is ?

Comment: Using the same name is definitely not going to work. You could use an array, but then you would have to change your back-end as well: `name="ckb[SOME_ID]"` or `name="ckb[]"` if you can identify them uniquely by the values.

Comment: @jeroen so if I use different names , all I gotta do is create a field for each checkbox and a php value similar to the one above ? should I make the checkbox values all the same ?

Comment: @pawel7318 well I was asking if its even possible and how if so ...

Comment: @Azizi I don't care much for checkbox values, I normally use a unique id like `name="ckb[1]"` `name="ckb[25]"` and use `isset()` on the server-side to see which ones were checked.

Comment: @Azizi 
My answer did not help you?

Comment: certainly did , thank you :) however I'm facing this problem today 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308928/error-when-submitting-checkbox-to-mysql/23309103?noredirect=1#comment35684931_23309103

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use such html:

```
<form>
<input type='checkbox' name='data[]' value='YourId' /> Data
<input type='checkbox' name='data[]' value='AnotherId' /> AnotherData
<input type='checkbox' name='data[]' value='OneMoreId' /> OneMoreData
// others
</form>
```

How to handle this data in php?

Use this:

```
$engineeringworkshops = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['cob']); 
// handle data from checkboxes
foreach($_POST['data') as $item) {
    // do something in item
    $sql="INSERT INTO courses (studentid, engworkshops) VALUES ('$item', '$engineeringwokshops')";
}
```

Comment: You need to put the (unique...) value back in or use a unique ID for each checkbox to know which ones were checked.

Comment: Yes, id should be unique anyway (not only in this case). Code from my answer will insert only data, which was selected. `$_POST` or `$_GET` will contain only selected checboxes ID's, wouldn't it?

Comment: No, it will contain only the values, ID's are not sent to the server. If two are checked they will have indexes of 0 and 1, but it could be checkbox 1 and 2, 1 and 3 or 2 and 3. And that's with only 3 checkboxes...

Comment: Aaaaaaah my bad. I know I know I know this, sorry. I mixed up attributes `value` and `id`. My mistake. Have to go to bed, I think. Thank you. I edited my answer. Sorry.

Comment: shouldn't it be something like 

$engineeringworkshops = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['data']);
?

and do I have to define $item ?

Comment: @Azizi you don't have to define `$item`.

Comment: @SharikovVladislav what type should I use for the database ? and do I have to create a field for each checkbox ?

Comment: Edit your question and explain what you want to achieve? As I think add some courses to some student? You have table `Students`, you have table `Courses`, right? Now you have to create table, where you will store link of Student-Course, say, `StudentsVsCourses` or `CoursesOfStudents`. You will store there `studentId`, `courseId` and some more additional data. When you will handle your form data in php you will just make query and add to this link table some rows, representing relationships between student and courses.

Comment: `and do I have to create a field for each checkbox ?` — did you mean in database? No, you don't need to create new field for each checkbox.