# Error when submitting checkbox to MySQL

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, checkbox

I have the following php code for submitting the form to the database the only problem is with the checkboxes ... on submitting the form this shows up

**Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed in /srv/disk6/1662822/www/website.co.nf/connect-mysql.php on line 16**

```
<?php
    $host="host.com" ;
    $username="1662822_db1" ;
    $password="awesomepassword" ;
    $db_name="1662822_db1" ;
    $tbl_name="courses" ;
        $dbcon = mysqli_connect("$host","$username","$password","$db_name") ;           

        if (!$dbcon) {
        die('error connecting to database'); }

        echo 'Courses successfully registerd , ' ;  

    // escape variables for security
    $studentid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon, $_POST['studentid']); echo $studentid;
    **$ckb = join (', ', $_POST['ckb']);** 


    **$sql="INSERT INTO courses (studentid, ckb)
    VALUES ('$studentid', '$ckb')";**

    if (!mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbcon));
}
echo "  Thank you for using IME Virtual Registeration  ";   
        mysqli_close($dbcon);
?>
```

The error is 
**Warning:** join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed in /srv/disk6/1662822/www/website.com/connect-mysql.php on line 16

I understand its something to do with join function (obviously) but I don't understand what it is...

HTML code for checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb" value="strenthofmaterials";>
<label for="StrengthofMaterials"> Strength Of Materials </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb" value="dynamics";>
<label for="StrengthofMaterials"> dynamics </label>
```

it goes on for all other choices with only changing the value of each checkbox

another piece of information , the ckb field in mysql database type in tinyint with a default value of 0 ...and I'm guessing its not the type I'm looking for ..?

Comment: `$_POST['ckb']` may not be an array .. try a `var_dump($_POST['ckb']);` and check or post it here.

Comment: to make sure I got you ... an array in the form itself right ?
name=ckb[] and not just name=ckb ?

Comment: I don't have an idea on how your `<form>` is structured. You need to post that so it will be easy for anyone to help you out.

Comment: its like this  

<input type="checkbox" name="ckb" value="strenthofmaterials";>
<label for="StrengthofMaterials"> Strength Of Materials </label>

and it goes on for all other choices changing only the value ..

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I trid var_dump($_POST['ckb']); but it didnt work

Comment: string(8) "fluidlab" 
Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed in /srv/disk6/1662822/www/imejo.co.nf/connect-mysql.php on line 16

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran this is what popped , with the string(8)"fluidlab" ..something new , btw thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your checkboxes should be in the form of an array...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb[]" value="strenthofmaterials";>
<label for="StrengthofMaterials"> Strength Of Materials </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb[]" value="dynamics";>
<label for="StrengthofMaterials"> dynamics </label>
```

**Note :** It is `ckb[]` instead of just `ckb`

Comment: fixed but its still giving the same error 

"Courses successfully registerd , 2012025060string(6) "fluid2" 
Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed in /srv/disk6/1662822/www/imejo.co.nf/connect-mysql.php on line 16
Thank you for using IME Virtual Registeration"

Comment: @Azizi, Change the tinyint type to `varchar(100)`

Comment: still giving the same message , I noticed its always the last checkbox selected appears in the beginning of the error for example if i choose

dynamics,strength and fluid2 ... the message appears string(6)"fluid2" .. and so on for different selections

Answer (score 0):

```
$ckb = array();
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $val){
    $ckb[] = (int) $val;
}
$ckb = implode(',', $ckb);
```

Try this one. $ckb should be an array.
For security purpose $val is converted in integer.

Comment: still giving the same error message
Courses successfully registerd , 2012025060string(6) "fluid2" 
Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed in /srv/disk6/1662822/www/imejo.co.nf/connect-mysql.php on line 16
Thank you for using IME Virtual Registeration

Comment: depending on what I select it gives sting(6)"fluid2" string(8)"fluidlab" am i defining the type wrong ?....etc

Comment: @Azizi Using this code you are getting of "join()".? It working properly when I run that code

Comment: @Azizi change $ids to $ckb, and then use print_r($ckb); exit;  and check whether you are getting values in it or not and have you made changes as suggested by Shankar .?

Comment: done, still giving the same error ...
here's another screenshot... http://i.imgur.com/R0VaApN.png

Comment: what should my field type be ? it is currently set to varchar(100)

Comment: and yes changes suggested by Shankar have been made 
I changed the field type to varchar(100)
and edited the name to ckb[]

Comment: @Azizi : It seems everything is fine. But as you said you are not getting the answer, can please share full screen shot of your html file, php file and output in browser?

Comment: this is the html code http://i.imgur.com/HU4j0TU.png (not full because its very long, <form action="connect-mysql.php" method="POST" id="form3" name="form3">